Odd sections on mesh
I've been trying that at a new body model to one of the games I've been playing. I have been able to import the model but oddly enough you can see the seams and I  saw when looking at it in Blender you definitely can see them.
Is there a way for me to reduce the visibility of these within the game I tried merging by distance which did pretty good. But it's not supported in the game's rendering process for the mesh.
I wanted to know if there was any known way to reduce it I tried smoothing and auto smoothing and it didn't help reduce the visibility of the lines.



Hello could you please share your object or at least a part of it so that we try to fix it? https://blend-exchange.com/

The file is uploaded

You have gaps between the faces, you need to select all and merge the vertices by distance (M)

That was the first thing I did, but when I do it and I try to export it in it's correct format it gives me an error message saying that Mesh's UV islands aren't physically separated. Which is weird because when I checked the UV maps they're fine.

Yes that's weird, UVs are different thing than mesh
